# Hide (Suppress Showing) Global Public Parameter Dialog Box (Modelica Dymola)

Tags: modelica

I have a `parameter` that is always calculated from other parameters, and needs to be `public` so it can be used by other component models in my project. Basically, it is a *global* `parameter` in an object very similar to the `TIL.SystemInformationManager` object.

Because it is calculated, it is meaningless to show it in any dialog box; and using `annotation(dialog(enable=false))` could lead to confusion and frustration because the user sees it *always* disabled for no good reason.

Because it must be `public`, I cannot use the `protected` keyword.

It cannot be `final` because it is set by the model using it.

Lastly, it must be a `parameter`, and not a variable, because I use it to dimension an array.

Here is the model. The idea is that in `sim2` you set the connector type `ct` which then calculates the size `n` of the array `myArray` that is used in all the connector components:

```
package VerySimpleSIM

  model Sim2

    parameter Integer ct = 0 "Connector type";
    final parameter Integer n = if (ct > 0) then 2 else 0;

  end Sim2;

  connector MyConnector "Connector with array size set by global parameter n"

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //This parameter is always set by the component using the connector,
    //so I don't want to show it in any dialog box.
    parameter Integer n;
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Real myArray[n];

  end MyConnector;

  model Creator

  protected 
    outer Sim2 sim2 "System information manager";

  public 
    MyConnector cnctrB(final n=sim2.n) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{80,-10},{100,10}})));

  equation 
    //Create arbitrary values for testing: time + 0.1 * {1,2,...,n}
    cnctrB.myArray = {time + 0.1 * i for i in 1:sim2.n};
  end Creator;

  model Changer

  protected 
    outer Sim2 sim2 "System information manager";

  public 
    MyConnector cnctrA(final n=sim2.n) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,-10},{-80,10}})));
    MyConnector cnctrB(final n=sim2.n) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{80,-10},{100,10}})));

  equation 
    //Output = sin(2 * pi * input)
    cnctrB.myArray = Modelica.Math.sin(2 * Modelica.Constants.pi .* cnctrA.myArray);
  end Changer;

  model TestSim2

    inner Sim2 sim2(ct=1) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{20,20},{40,40}})));

    Changer changer annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
    Creator creator annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,-10},{-20,10}})));
  equation 
    connect(creator.cnctrB, changer.cnctrA) annotation (Line(points={{-21,0},{-9,0}}));
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
  end TestSim2;
end VerySimpleSIM;
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2211

Answer (score 3):

You can show/hide a parameter using the `public` and `protected` keywords as shown in the following example:

```
model protectedParameter
  parameter Real p1=1 "Visible parameter";
  parameter Real p2=3.14 "another visible parameter";
protected
  parameter Real derivedParameter=p1+p2+p3 "Hidden (protected) parameter";
public
  parameter Real p3=2.71 "yet another visible parameter";
equation
  // equations from here on
  ...
end protectedParameter;
```

Alternatively, you can put the `final` keyword in front of the parameter declaration and Dymola, at least, will hide it from the dialogs.

Best regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Thanks for the response.
My problem was that I needed to pass this parameter around in order to dimension arrays in other models, so it had to be `public`.
If I am still missing something (which is *highly* likely), please let me know. If I am not, then I think I should clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `annotation(dialog(connectorSizing=true))` to suppress showing a parameter in a dialog box. E.g., change the line that reads,

```
    parameter Integer n;
```

to read,

```
    parameter Integer n annotation(dialog(connectorSizing=true));
```

Comment: According to the Modelica specification `connectorSizing` has nothing to do with the hiding of results. Also just to be clear `connectorSizing` can only be used for `Integer` types. So even if this could be used in some non-standard following tools it would not work in general. Also a small typo, the annotation is `Dialog` (Modelica is case sensitive).

Comment: @Dietmar 1.  Indeed, my question "has nothing to do with the hiding of results". Take another look at the question. 2.  Have you tried this in Dymola? I just tested all eight combinations of `Integer`/`Real` `Dialog`/`dialog` and `true`/`false`. The only thing that Dymola cared about **with respect to displaying the `parameter` in the dialog box** was `true`/`false`. I have Dymola Version 2016 FD01 (32-bit), 2015-10.13. What version are you using? If all this is true, and you down-voted me, would you consider removing it?